# How to start express server in grunt?

Tags: angularjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I generated my angular 1.0 app with Yeoman. The gruntfile does not contain a express server config:

```
connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                connect.static('./app/styles')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
```

How can I add an express server configuration to it? Can I do this with grunt-contrib-connect?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "grunt-express-server" https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-express-server.  I don't know if you can use "grunt-contrib-connect" for this.